# How can you put new songs from a computer to an apple device after you wiped the computer and it counts as a new one?

Tags: data-synchronization, ipad

I recently wiped my computer without backing it up because it was overwhelmed by viruses, and I just bought a new CD, which I planned to put on my iPad 2. The only problem is that the computer is now recognized as a new computer, and wants to erase all my non-apple bought content. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a product like [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to first copy your music off of the iPad on to the computer.  Then use the copied music to rebuild iTunes and then when the music on the iPad gets wiped it won't matter as it will get replaced with what you copied to the computer and added to iTunes.